# jQuery Draggable - get position

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

:) I can't get the position ot objects relative to it's container. 
I get only the position on whole page.Here is my code:

```
<style>
   .draggable { width: 150px; height: 0px; cursor:move; bottom: border:solid; border-color:#000; }
   <?PHP if($userinfo->use_colors != '0'): ?>
   #container { width: 450px; height:80px; background-color:<?=$userinfo->background?>; }
   <?PHP else: ?>
   #container { width: 450px; height:80px; background:url(/backgrounds/<?=$userinfo->image?>); }
   <?PHP endif; ?>
   </style>
<script>
   $(function() {
   $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ cursor: "move",containment: "#container", scroll: false,
   drag: function() {
   var position = $(this).position();
   var xPos = $(this).position().left;
   var yPos = $(this).position().top;
   $(this).text('x: ' + xPos + 'y: ' + yPos);
   }
                                            });
   $( "#draggable2" ).draggable({ cursor: "move",containment: "#container", scroll: false });
   $( "#draggable3" ).draggable({ cursor: "move",containment: "#container", scroll: false });
   $( "#draggable4" ).draggable({ cursor: "move",containment: "#container", scroll: false });
   });
   </script>


<div id="container">
   <div id="draggable" class="draggable" style="position:relative;top:0px;left:80px;">
   .::[ NowPlaying SIGnature ]::.
   </div>
   <div id="draggable2" class="draggable" style="position:relative;top:20px;left:80px;">
   Artist - title
   </div>
   <div id="draggable3" class="draggable" style="position:relative;top:40px;left:80px;">
   Album: (Year)
   </div>
   <div id="draggable4" class="draggable" style="position:relative;top:60px;left:80px;">
   Genre: 
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
var xPos = $(this).css('left');
var yPos = $(this).css('top');
```

...instead.

Comment: Hm, this way works, but when I drag object to lowest point, and let it ,and drag it again i can get  out of container. I want to stay inside #container /450,80px/

Comment: Don't know what this has to do with your question. My suggestion doesn't change anything on the drag/drop-behaviour, it just retrieves some values.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I yesterday I fall in sleep too late. :) I just have to get why it get out. Thanks for answer. :)

Comment: I'm getting pos now with .position().left; and *.top;

Parent container is set as relative that fixed it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I spent about an hour using the $(this).position() - $(this).css('left') made sense and worked like charm.

Comment: to put it all together, set the parent as relative, and the draggable divs to absolute. Then using `position().top` and `position().left` works perfectly!